# How to be sure they are uploading certain files

Tags: php, file-upload, mime-types

Ok, I am allowing (within a script) for certain types of files to be uploaded via an Forum Admin Defined approach!  How can I tell if these files are of the type that the Admin has set to be sure they are not fake files.  I currently am using a mime-types approach, but different browsers can set different mime-types, so this doesn't really help much.  Checking the file extension doesn't help either, since people can get around this by giving it an extension that is allowed, but would be of a different file type.

Perhaps there is a reference somewhere of a way to check the bytes within many different types of files to be sure that it is of the correct type?  Perhaps this can be faked also, but atleast it would be a bit more accurate when using a form to upload files into and submitting them.

Can someone please help me with ideas on this?

Thanks :)

Comment: What sort of files are you expecting? Depending on the file, you could read their header to see what type of file they are.

Comment: Well, the Admin selects what files they want to be allowed to be uploaded, by placing in the extension of each file extension allowed separated by commas.  So, now I just need to `explode(',', $extensions)` on it and make sure that the file type is correct for all extensions within that array that gets returned.  Is there a way to do this?  What files can you read the header on??  And what files can you not read the header on??  Do you have an idea on a better way to implement this that would be better for security and/or code-wise?

Comment: Have a look at [`mime_content_type()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php).

Comment: whatever approach you end up taking I would suggest also calling PHP's is_executable function to avoid anything that can be run on your server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[PECL `fileinfo`](http://php.net/manual/function.finfo-file.php) (or built-in >5.3) will inspect the byte signatures of files to guess their mimetypes, so it protects against people simply changing the file extension.  It is still possible in some cases to include malicious bytes in a file that matches the appropriate byte signature for a filetype.

From the PHP docs:

```
// Procedural style
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE); // return mime type ala mimetype extension
echo finfo_file($finfo, $filename);
finfo_close($finfo);

// OO style
$finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
echo $finfo->file($filename);
$finfo->close();
```

On a Unix server, I believe `finfo_file()` consults the same byte signature database as the GNU `file` utility.

Comment: @Phoenix I think that's the third time this week you've removed the i10n from one of my PHP doc URLs.  I'll remember to do it myself from now on :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't ever trust user input. Checking for a given filetype/mimetype should never be used as a way to prevent people from uploading malicious content to your server. If the goal is server security, then simply don't allow content to be executed on the server if it's uploaded by a user. For files that other people download, make sure to place a disclaimer that the content was user-generated and is not guaranteed to be virus-free.